# 32U4 based board sometimes does not run setup

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, atmega32u4

I have a custom PCB using 32U4.
Sometimes when I switch the board on, the code of setup() function does not run. But this is quite unfrequent, the board usually works fine. This just happens from time to time.
I have tested with minimal arduino code just lighting up a LED during setup() nothing more.
Bootloader is Arduino Leonardo.
Here is the board schmatics :
[image]

Comment: There's no bypass capacitors. Is this intentional? Put bypass caps and see if it works better.

Comment: Thank you @Justme for pointing that out! You are probably right. Do you have recommandations to make for these bypass capacitors?

Comment: the ones recommended by manufacturer hardware design application notes, examples and datasheets